# "Неважна" или "не важна"?

Tags: орфография

Скажите, пожалуйста, "неважна" пишется вместе или раздельно? И очень важно выяснить, какое правило это объясняет! Заранее благодарю!

"Беспризорники часто ощущают, что их роль неважна, потому что они не имеют, как другие, дома и семьи".

Answer (score 2):

Здесь слитно, потому что в предложении нет этих грам­ма­ти­че­ских усло­вий: про­ти­во­по­став­ле­ние, сло­ва «отнюдь», «вовсе», «дале­ко», отри­ца­тель­ные место­име­ния (никто, ничто, ника­кой, ничей, нисколь­ко, неко­го, нече­го) или наре­чия (нигде, нику­да, нико­гда, негде, неку­да, неко­гда, ниот­ку­да, никак, неза­чем и пр.) — в таких случаях рас­смат­ри­ва­е­мое сло­во, неза­ви­си­мо от его при­над­леж­но­сти к части речи, пишет­ся раз­дель­но с отри­ца­тель­ной части­цей «не». В таких выска­зы­ва­ни­ях дела­ет­ся явный акцент на отри­ца­ние чего-либо.

Примеры:

По дан­ной про­бле­ме мне ваше мне­ние не важ­но, а безразлично.

Отнюдь не важ­но для меня, что он рас­ска­жет об этом случае.

Вовсе не важ­но, куда нас заве­дет эта тропинка.

Далеко не важ­но, кто при­дет пер­вым на встречу.

[Источник](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/kak-pishetsya-slovo-nevazhno-ili-ne-vazhno.html)

Comment: Выбор слитного написания НЕ в приведенном предложении верен, но вот объяснение не кажется вполне корректным. Можно посмотреть в Нацкорпусе раздельные написания "не важно, не важна", где нет ни усилительных слов, но противопоставления. Например: https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=не+важна

Comment: Спасибо, не все так просто в этой теме, оказывается)

Comment: Да, не всё...  Вы верно назвали формальные признаки, но есть еще решения по смыслу, по структурно-интонационному анализу. Это предложение сложное, там слово вписывается в общую структуру, а это признак для слитного письма. Сравнить: "ТЕма не важна, лишь бы на неё набежали посетители. Тема неважнА, лишь бы на неё набежали посетители".  Здесь раздельное написание при логическом выделении предыдущего слова. Но я все-таки поставлю вам лайк за правильное решение.

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем, кто помог найти ответ!